# React Routing Variable in the link

Tags: reactjs, variables, react-router

I am trying to use react router to redirect to a different page, however the problem I have is that I have to put a variable inside and I can't make it to work.

Here is what I have (in the code section):

The ":id" part of the URL has to be ignored because it's populated from the database, that is why I need to use a variable that is passed from the server.

The problem is that when I put something like {variable} inside "" or without it doesn't work.

`<Switch> <Route exact path="/Page1/:id/Page2" component={Component} />      <Route path="/Page1/:id/Page2/Page3" component={Component1} /> </Switch>`

I want to use the variable so that it takes it and links correctly.

Can you please tell me if you know how to help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you can make use of URL parameters and achieve what you are looking for.

   2. I assume that this can also be fixed by defining the association between the two entities of the database which you are trying to fetch. I hope you are more or less trying to address a Header---Items scenario.

Regards
Pavan Bhamidipati

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to insert variable inside url. You can try either of them.

```
<Route exact path=`/Page1/${variable}/Page2` component={Component} />
```

or

```
<Route exact path={'/Page1/'+variable+'/Page2} component={Component} />
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! However I do have one question:

If I put the variable directly my page doesn't load, if I put and empty tag content it does.

Here is what I mean:

```<Route exact path={'' + variable} component={App} /> works```
```<Route exact path={variable} component={App} /> doesn't work```

On the second route here is how I made it work:

```<Route path={variable + '/SecondPage'}```

How do I make it so the variable is the exact path?

Comment: can you elaborate what is the value this variable holding?

Comment: The variable is formData.productUrl.url which is taking the URL from a json object that is returned form the base. The URL itself is /Page1/Page2/Page3

Comment: so I think in case of `path={' '+variable}` which is working because here `+` concatenating with variable and due to precedence variable it gets converted into string i.e. `path='/Page1/Page2'` while in case of `path={variable}` variable is not string it might be converted into like `path=/Page1/Page2` hence it is not working. Also in case of `path={variable +'/SecondPage'}` it's working because it is getting converted into string due to concatenation.
so i would suggest you to use variable using method 1 as above e.g. `path=\`${variable}+'/SecondPage'\` or path=\`'${variable}'\``

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by inserting *variable* as

```
<Link to={`/getItemsFromCart/${variable}`} >
   Cart
</Link>
```